# Upgrading to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, lts

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS about a month ago. And just my luck, a few weeks later they release 16.04 LTS. I was wondering how, or if, I could upgrade to 16.04 LTS? Do I have to do a clean install, or can I upgrade while still in 14.04 (like how Windows allows you to upgrade from Windows 8.1 to 10)?

I'm just worried that I would have to backup my files, uninstall 14.04, and then install 16.04.

Comment: Wait a bit and it will tell you there is a new release when you update your computer in the normal way. Your documents and programs will be preserved. Still sensible to do a backup - but everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

a) Upgrade from 14.04 LTS, although you should wait for the offficial upgrade offer made by the software updater (somewhere in July) since the Canonical team releases that simple update in July, once everything's been checked. Alternatively, you can force upgrade right away.

Here's how: http://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-to-16-04/

or

b) (recommended): Do a clean install (by booting and erase disk and install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS throught the installation disk/USB), which makes things less likely to go wrong (kernel upgrades, other applications support, since it's officially not validated for upgrade). Especially if you don't have any data as of yet.

Here's how: http://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-to-16-04/

Either way, backup your important files.

Comment: Awesome, I'll probably do the clean install. Thanks!